# How to obtain and convert custom json data as strings in android

Tags: android, json

I've googled around and found many tutorials(duplicates) and tips about json for android, but I find it difficult to perceive. I find it hard to get the score and the names as strings from the following json that I've retrieved from my database. I tried to get the result object first and get the names and scores but not certain how I can get manage to get it from [{},{}].

Are there some easy examples or tips? It sounds silly, but I need your help. I would like to hear from you!

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Bobby",
      "score": "44"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Mike",
      "score": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let,

```
String s = "{"result": [{"id": "3","name": "Bobby","score": "44"},{"id": "2","name": "Mike","score": "10"}]}";  

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray result= jsonObject .getJSONArray("result");

for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = json.getString("name");
    String score = json.getString("score");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In json {} means object and [] means array.
First you should create a Json object from your string. Then get result as an array. In result you have tow objects that you can get them with their index.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray result= jsonObject .getJSONArray("result");
// Now we can iterate through the array
for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = (JSONObject) result.get(i);
    String name = item.getString("name");
    String score = item.getString("score");
}
```

Comment: score is int or String?

Comment: sorry, it is String

Answer (score 1):

it's so simply

Just do like this

first make a model for according to your need like id, name and score

then use this

`JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
JSONArray results = jObj.getJSONArray("result");`

now the values are in array use that array to show values

Answer (score 1):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to deserialize from JSON to a Plain Old Java Object (POJO).

1. Include GSON library in your Android project:`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`
2. Create your JAVA POJO model:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       @SerializedName("result")
       private List mResult;

   public List<Result> getResults() {
       return mResult;
   }

   private static class Result {
       @SerializedName("id")
       private String mId;

       @SerializedName("name")
       private String mName;

       @SerializedName("score")
       private String mScore;

       public String getId() {
           return mId;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return mName;
       }

       public String getScore() {
           return mScore;
       }
   }


   }
   ```
3. Deserialize your JSON to your POJO object:
   `Gson gson = new Gson();`
   `gson.fromJson(you_json_string, MyClass.class);`
4. Once you have your deserialized object you just need to call your getters:

   `getResults().get(0).getScore()`